# Azure Function: switch from consumption to premium plan for 1 hour daily automatically?

Tags: azure-functions

My instance of func app currently under consumption plan.
There is one timer trigger logic that needs to make bunch on http requests - 10k and fails due to consumption plan "connections" limitation.

Is it possible to automatically switch to premium plan for 1 hour daily and then switch it back to consumption?

Or maybe azure function was not the best choice here - basically I need to execute some logic daily (it takes about 1 hour on 1 core PC), so it does not make sense to pay more but just for this 1 hour of work.

**Update 1**: Is there a recommended approach for azure platform to run .net code on timer and only for 1 hour a day? And pay only for this 1 hour

Any suggestions?
Thank you!